# How to send the form data to my cs page's WebMethod through Ajax JSON?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to send my form data to webmethod through jquery.ajax and json but i am unable to send or get any error in the log. can any one can guide me through this or where am i going wrong?. The .ajax method is not executing and giving and alert as "undefined" ?

```
    function Submit() {
    debugger;
    var advantages = [];
    var features = [];
    var Elig_crit = [];
    var Elig_value = [];

    $('#AdvantagesContainer .Advantages').each(function () {

        //var txtAdvantages = $(".Advantages")
        //for (var i = 0; i < txtAdvantages.length; i++) {


        advantages.push($(this).val());

        //}
    });

    $('#FeaturesContainer .Features').each(function () {


        features.push($(this).val());
    });


    $('.Eligibility .EligibilityCrit_TxtBox').each(function () {

        Elig_crit.push($(this).val());

    });


    $('.Eligibility .EligibilityVal_TxtBox').each(function () {

        Elig_value.push($(this).val());
    });

    debugger;
    var objData = { Category: $('#ddlInsCategory option:selected').val(), Company: $("#ddlCompanyName option:selected").val(), PlanName: $("#<%=txtPlanName.ClientID%>").val(), PlanDesc: $("#<%=txtPlanDesc.ClientID%>").val(), features: features, advantages: advantages, Criteria: Elig_crit, Value: Elig_value }
    //var jsonData = JSON.stringyfy({ objData: objData }); 
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Edit.ascx/Save",
        data: objData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert("Success");
}
```

Currently i havent written any code into my webmethod. I have just made the skeleton to see what data does the json throws.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void Save(object objData)
    {


    }
```

Comment: Post your *Save* method also

Comment: also use *error* instead of *failure*

Comment: change *failure* to *error*, and then try to debug your code. Is that reaches your method or no?

Comment: @Khazratbek I havent written anything in my webmthod i have made the skeleton to see what data is coming

Comment: add *int i = 1;* line to your method and add breakpoint

Comment: I have replaced the failure with error now i am getting alert as "undefined" am i doin any mistake in my objData

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Strong Type at your server side. This will have proper mappings and its very easy and recommended way to work with jQuery ajax.

Simply create a custom type at your server side which have property names matching with that of the `key` in your Javascript object like this (Make sure you have the same name and change the datatype accordingly):-

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Category { get; set; }
   public string Company { get; set; }
   public string PlanName { get; set; }
   public string PlanDesc { get; set; }
   public List<string> features{ get; set; }
   public List<string> advantages { get; set; }
   public List<string> Criteria{ get; set; }
   public List<string> Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, change your `WebMethod` to accept this Type as parameter:-

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Save(Foo objData)
{


}
```

Finally send the JSON data from client:-

```
var objData = { Category: $('#ddlInsCategory option:selected').val(), ....
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ objData: objData });
```

Comment: I tried applying your logic but i am getting an error as JSON.stringyfy is not a function @rahulsingh

Comment: @user3682373 - It's `stringify` and not `stringyfy`, I copy pasted your code earlier :D

Comment: yes my mistake there, i corrected the syntax stringify and it is giving "undefined" in alert message. ? @RahulSingh

Comment: @user3682373 - It is not hitting the server method? Have you checked the developer tool? Please chekc what is the error there.

Comment: yes i checked the developer tool its giving undefined error on alert and its not hitting the server method. i tried sending a simple string but its not hitting the server method. i dont know why  ? @RahulSingh

Comment: @user3682373 - What you are passing in `data` parameter of jQuery ajax? Currently you have `data: objData` it should be `data: jsonData `

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods how you can achieve this:

Because you have tagged WebMethod. You can add a scriptManager to your server-side form which will make all of your WebMethods available in client side.

**using scriptManager**

1. Add a script manager to your server-side form
2. in case if you are using friendly URLs you need to add the page extension manually. **ALSO** in your RouteConfig set RedirectMode.Off, if you have redirectMode.permanent your ajax call will fail.

   ```
           if (stringEndsWith(PageMethods.get_path(), "aspx")) {
           } else {
               PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
           };
   ```

call your WebMethods directly from your javascript using PageMEthods.

```
PageMethods.FN_TEST(your_parameter, onSucess, onError);
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);

            },
            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
```

Your page:

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
```

allow your webpage handle script services by adding  ScriptService

```
[ScriptService]
public partial class your_page : System.Web.UI.Page{
```

... and your web methods

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static void FN_TEST(string iParam)
{
    return "You have sent me " + iParam;
    // Your result will be JSONised and look like this {d:Json_object}
    //

}}
```

**using Ajax post **
assuming your WebMethod is set up as above. your ajax call will look like this:

```
"ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "dataFilter": function (data) {
                // as web methods return {d:object} this method gets rid of the extra d container in your result set.
                var msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                    return msg.d;
                else
                    return msg;
            },
            "dataType": "json",
            "url": "your_page.aspx/FN_TEST", // your web methode

            "data": function (d) {
                // add your params here,
                return JSON.stringify({ iParam: $("#your_field").val()});
            },
            "success": function (data) {
                // do something with your result

            },


        },
```

if you want to customize more, you can JSONise all your form-fields, send as string, parse the string back to JSON in your webmethod and process continue your stuffs.

**Edit**
above code is not full code, modify as per your need
oh btw.. if you are using postback you can retrieve your formfields in the request.form collection. I assume you are not interested in this

Comment: I tried debugging my code and i found out that my json is unable to resolve the url i am providing it because it is a DNN cms so i though to replace my url with this 'url: "/DesktopModules/InsuranceModule/Edit.ascx/Save' but its still not hitting the webmethod. I wanted to know what url should we give in json when working with DNN and its user controls @krishkm

Comment: open up your browser console and monitor the network requests do you see failed ajax call? if you are using VS look into the applications insights it will show all callbacks.